# Ionic 3 - get data in a variable with this (\"9876543210\", \"9876543211\") format

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to retrieve all user's contact numbers in a variable with this format: \"9876543210\", \"9876543211\", \"9876543211\",...

I have loaded all the contact numbers from database,
Here is my code:

```
loadContacts()
{
    let contacts: any = [];
    firebase.database().ref('users').orderByKey().once('value', (items: any) => {

        //console.log(items);
        items.forEach((item) => {

            if(item.val().contact_no != '0')
            {
                contacts.push({
                    contactNo: item.val().contact_no
                });
            }
            this.contactList = contacts;
           console.log("Contacts: ",this.contactList);
       });
   },
   (error) => {
    console.log("Error: ", error);
   });
}
```

loadContacts() retrieves contacts in this format:

[image: loaded contacts format]

I want all the contact numbers in this format: \"9876543210\", \"9876543211\", \"9876543211\",...
and store it in a variable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
loadContacts()
{
    let contacts: any = [];
    firebase.database().ref('users').orderByKey().once('value', (items: any) => {
    //console.log(items);
    items.forEach((item) => {

      if(item.val().contact_no != '0')
      {
        contacts.push(item.val().contact_no);
      }
      this.contactList = contacts;
      //console.log("Contacts: ",this.contactList);
    });

    var length = this.contactList.length;
      console.log("Length: ",length);
      if(length > 0)
      {
        for(var i = 0; i <= length; i++)
        {
          if(i > 0)
          {
            this.contacts += '\\\"' + this.contactList[i] + '\\\",' ;
          }
        }
        var contact = this.contacts;
        this.contacts = contact.slice(9,-16);
        console.log("Formatted Contacts: ",this.contacts);
      }
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("Error: ", error);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the result to string

```
    if(item.val().contact_no != '0')
        {
            let editedContact:string = '\"'+item.val().contact_no+'\"';
            contacts.push({
                contactNo: editedContact
            });
        }
```

console.log will skip the `\`, but you can get it in the template

```
<pre>{{contactList|json}}</pre>
```